# ant buildfile setting javac location

Tags: java, xml, ant, build

I'm editing the buildfile of an old project. When I add some jar files to the project that use Java 1.6, it won't build. It says

```
[javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.6
```

So clearly I need to tell the ant buildfile to use javac 1.6.

How do I do this? I have JDK1.6 installed on my system, but the default javac is 1.5. I don't want to change the default javac... I just want to set the javac location in this one proejct to JDK1.6/bin/javac. **How do I do this in the XML of an ant buildfile?**

Thanks,
ktm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper script in which you change your `JAVA_HOME` before executing `ant`.

e.g. `build.sh`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk1.6
ant "$@"
```

Now when you call `build.sh` it will use  java6 for both `javac`, `java` and any other commands.

IMO this is better than fiddling with the `build.xml` (and forking a new `javac` process).

Answer (score 7):

This was pulled from the [javac task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html#compilervalues)

```
<javac srcdir="" 
         destdir=""
         executable="path-to-java16-home/bin/javac" 
         fork="true"
         taskname="javac1.6" />
```

Comment: I'm still getting "invalid target release: 1.6". Maybe I don't have an up-to-date version of ant?

Comment: but this one I need to hardcode the path, what if I compile that code in server, then I am require to change the executable path.