# Ant source compile jdk path

Tags: ant, javac

How can I tell ant to compile my project using a particular version of jdk?

I'm working on a tool that compiles various projects who's requirement in terms of jdk versions differ

I would prefer something like setting the path of my java library via a properties file rather than changing my JAVA_HOME variable  everytime(as mentioned in many posts I've found here)

Is there a way I could set an attribute for my javac property so that it looks up to that and compiles my code with a particular version of jdk?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need this in your ant buildfile:

```
<javac srcdir="" 
         destdir=""
         executable="path-to-java16-home/bin/javac" 
         fork="true"
         taskname="javac1.6" />
```

taken from: [ant buildfile setting javac location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865245/ant-buildfile-setting-javac-location)

-fork needs to be true (or yes according to: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

-executable needs to be the path to your desired java compiler.

-srcdir and destdir are the respective directories of your source and class files

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a try.